# Query from electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism

We know by Faraday's law that emf induced in a closed coil is given by the negative rate of change of magnetic flux associated with the coil....but is the induced electric field set up in any coil due electromagnetic induction always non conservative....for example, the one setup due to self induction or due to mutual induction?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by non conservative?

Comment: That the work done on a charged particle by the field as it moves in a closed loop is not zero

Comment: @user372205 Not sure of your context, because you don't mention what else is going on around all this, but the work done is typically supplied by an energy source in electric/electronic circuits. I think you need to completely elaborate the situation, in detail.

Comment: @jonk There isn't any specific scenario that I am enquiring about .I am asking that is the induced electric field in a closed coil due to the change in the magnetic flux associated with it, is always non conservative?For example, let us imagine a closed circular loop of a wire such that a magnetic flux B is associated with it.Now as this flux B changes, an electric field is setup in the wire which gives out an effective emf. Is this electric field non conservative.

Comment: Physics types interacting with engineers.  How many of us are Googling "non conservative"?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I came up with this while preparing for an engineering exam. Well then who should this from? I am new here

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The 4th year in electronics degrees include Maxwell's equations. (Not that I'd know from personal experience, having never taking any electronics courses.) However, I've taught at the largest 4-yr university and am a little aware of the curriculum there.

Comment: @user372205 I still don't know what you are talking about. Sorry. It reads as hand-waving to me, not sufficiently precise. Can you reference the engineering exam problem that caused you to ask this question? I think I could get more from that. For example, you write: "the change in the magnetic field associated with it" and I don't know what "it" is. Perhaps you do. But I can't seem to parse your words into a clear picture. That could be my problem. But there it is, anyway.

Comment: @jonk You want to know when (or if) I did Maxwell's equations....

Comment: @jonk I didn't come across while solving a question. I was just reading the theory. So lets try this again. Let us imagine a closed circular conducting wire and an infinite current carrying wire placed adjacently. The infinite current carrying wire has its own magnetic field. Many of these field lines pass through the adjacently placed circular loop, accounting for the  magnetic flux passing through the coil. Now as the current in the infinite wire is changed, we observe a net current developed in the loop(according to Faraday's law, as the flux passing through the loop changes).As magnetic fo

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat No, I wasn't asking you at all. I was instead using you as a foil to point that out to the general audience (not you) that this *might* be a legitimate question for this group and not transferred to the physics stack exchange forum, is all.

Comment: As magnetic forces cant do any work on the charges, the work done on them must be purely electrical. So therefore there exists an electric field in the loop which drives the motion of the charges. As for the conservative electric field we know, that as a charge moves moves from a point A to a point B and then back to point A in such a conservative electric field, the net work done by the field is zero. That doesn't happen in the above case as the charges move in circular loop.Therefore the electric field is non conservative. My question is that are are such electric fields induced due to

Comment: ...due to change in magnetic flux always non conservative. You can take examples of self induction or mutual induction. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: I think this question would be better suited in [physics.se], as it has lots to do with physics, and technically pretty much nothing to do with electronic circuit design, which is the area that this particular stack exchange site covers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in [physics.se], not [electronics.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An electric field will be conservative or not depending on its [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics))

A field with zero curl can be made with an arrangement of electrodes. If you take a point charge, it will gain and lose energy as you move it around. However, if you take it on a closed loop, the energy will be the same before and after the transit round the loop. The potential energy of the point charge at some location is another way of defining the electrical potential there.

A field with non-zero curl can be made by having an area of changing magnetic flux through it. If the loop path taken by the point charge misses the area of flux, its movement will be conservative. If the loop path encircles the flux, then its movement will be non-conservative, it will gain or lose energy in the motion. If the point charge makes several rotations around the flux, it will change energy each time it passes round. The potential of the field in this case is multi-valued, depending on how many times we have been round the flux.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking. Is the electric field in closed loop generated due to the changing magnetic flux through the loop always non conservative.

Comment: The energy of a point charge always changes when it circles the changing flux, so yes, if by non-conservative you mean gains or loses energy. In my dim'n'distant past, I recall our definition of non-conservative was that the change of energy going round a closed path depended on the path taken. By that definition, the change in energy is different depending on whether the path encloses the changing flux or not. Exactly the same argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. And just one more thing, what do you mean when you say - If the loop path taken by the point charge misses the area of flux, its movement will be conservative.

Comment: You already know what I'm attempting to say. As I'm not a student of topology, so not ready to trot out technical terms, and can't be bothered to draw a diagram, I' trying to convey the concept of 'winding number', how many times a conductor gets looped round a bundle of changing flux, and whether a loop links another loop. If the loop does not link the flux, then the potential is uni-valued, and the path taken does not change the energy. If the loop does link the flux, the potential is multi-valued, and the change of energy depends on the angle through which the charge moves wrt the flux.